# How can I run a cookbook with a specific version using chef-client?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I am having 2 cookbooks name as mycookbook and version 0.1.0 and 0.1.1 on chef server. Now I want to run only cookbook mycookbook version 0.1.1 using chef-client. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Found the answer with some hit and try

Ran following command

```
chef-client -o "recipe[mycookbook@0.1.1]"
```

This will call mycookbook version 0.1.1

**NOTE:** Running chef-client with the -o parameter will permanently override the runlist for that node.

Comment: That command will replace your runlist with new one with only that one cookbook. To use some version for all runs, you can specify exact version of cookbook into environment and assign that environment to your node.

Comment: @rastasheep Yes, I wanted to run a specific cookbook out of a run-list and that's what my requirement was. I knew about environment configuration and  cookbook version assignment too but was not a solution for this scenario (I don't have permissions to create new environment in chef server ).

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
chef-client -o COOKBOOK
```

Will override the default for this run only.
It will not change the default `run_list`.+

The command:

```
chef-client -r COOKBOOK
```

WILL set a new `run_list` and run the specified `COOKBOOK`.